# get rows if all foreign rows are inactive

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables. An "Account" can can many "Ads"

An account can have many ads.

I want to come up with a query that returns: any account that does not have any ads with the column `active` set to true.

If the account does not have any ads, then the query should not return it. And if only one of the ads related to that account has an ad with the column active set to true, then that should not be returned as well.

```
CREATE TABLE public.account
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('account_id_seq'::regclass),
    password text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    email_account_id bigint,
    phone_number text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    CONSTRAINT account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT account_email_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (email_account_id)
        REFERENCES public.email_account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)


CREATE TABLE public.ad
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('model_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    ad_url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    account_id bigint NOT NULL,
    active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    CONSTRAINT ad_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT ad_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
       REFERENCES public.account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
       ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give result for only those account who does not have any ads with the column active set to true

```
SELECT * FROM public.account a
LEFT JOIN public.ad ad ON (a.id = ad.account_id)
WHERE a.active = true AND ad.account_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

using `not exists()`:

```
select *
from public.account a
where not exists (
  select 1
  from public.ad d
  where a.id = d.account_id
    and d.active
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id
from public.account a
join public.ad ad on ad.account_id = a.id
group by a.id
having bool_or(ad.active) = false
```

If any related ad has `active = true` - `bool_or(ad.active)` will return `true` and the having condition will fail. So you will get accounts that have at least one related ad, and no of those ads is active.

Add more columns in the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses if needed.